# Prevent text overflowing in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am loading data from db. Sometimes I get longer string which causes text overflow. How can i make overflowing text to go to the next line?

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Card(
                color: (list[index]['author'] == widget.user.email) ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.grey[900],
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 40,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(list[index]['profilePicUrl']),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(list[index]['message'],softWrap: false, overflow: TextOverflow.clip, style: TextStyle(color: (list[index]['author'] == widget.user.email) ? Colors.black : Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                          Text(list[index]['author'], style: TextStyle(color: (list[index]['author'] == widget.user.email) ? Colors.grey[800] : Colors.grey, fontSize: 15)),
                      ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Comment: got that fixed? @petk

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your `Column` in `Expanded`, here's the sample code of your widget tree:

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded( // <-- This is what you need
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'This is very long line which can overflow on small screen devices easily',
            softWrap: false,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          Text('author'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: @PETKOMihalik Please post a minimal code of what error you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the Text in a Flexible

```
Flexible(
  child: Text('Some lengthy text for testing'),
)
```

Comment: You'll still need `overflow`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add maxLine in Text Widget with overFlow.

```
                                     Text('long text here',
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color:
                                                AppColors.subHeadingColor,
                                            fontFamily: 'Rubik',
                                            fontWeight:
                                                FontConstants.rubikMedium),
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I can understand that you are using the `Padding` widget to wrap your `message` and `author` properties in a `Text` widgets.

`Padding` widget is inside the another `Row` widget. **By default, a row or column occupies as much space along its main axis as possible**. So children will occupy almost entire space remaining in the `Row` widget after `CircularAvatar` whose size is fixed.

> The entire code (`Padding` widget after `CircularAvatar`) can be
> wrapped inside in the `Expanded` which will help you to prevent the
> pixel overflow error and add `softwrap :true` property to the `Text`
> widget which will make the message to appear in next consecutive
> lines.

This is the minimal version of your code, that I tried.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.greenAccent,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('profilePicUrl'),
        ),
//Wrapped inside the Expanded. 
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                    'messagemessagemessagemessagemessagemessagemessagemessagemessage12345678',
                    softWrap: true, // Set softwrap to true to make it to next line
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                Text('author',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 15)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Please let know if that works !! Cheers. .

Update :

[image: This is how it looks like..]